# run & kill a Bash command from Java

Tags: java, linux, bash, process, kill

I'm running arbitrary bash commands on Linux from a Java program using a `ProcessBuilder`:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("setsid", "/bin/bash", "-c", command);
process = pb.start();
```

The commands run fine, but when I try to kill them with `process.destroy()` they keep running. What's the best way to kill the command?

Comment: Why dont you create a command using shell or bash scripting to kill the process and simply call that from your JAVA.

Comment: Sounds good — how should I identify the process to be killed? Have the starting command write the pid to a file, then read that from the killing command? Is there a simpler way?

Comment: yeah that would be better, but the process if belongs to any service then you can kill that service by name, if the process related with any application then kill accordingly. and if not possible using the name, then yeah you right right but how you gonna track pid ?

Answer (score 0):

Write a bash script and run it from Java:

For running a program from Java by bash:

run.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
firefox # replace firefox by the program you like to start
```

For killing by program name:

kill.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
pkill -9 -x firefox # replace firefox by the program you like to kill
```

For killing the program by PID:

kill.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
kill -9 $PID
```

You can get the PID of program by start of program on follow way by bash:

```
firefox & $! # start the program and get the pid
echo $! # echo the pid of program
```

You can get the PID of a already running program by his name by bash:

```
pidof -x firefox
4561 # thats a sample of a output of a pid
```